# How to make SSRS run and send PDF report using one parameter, then change the parameter and run and send another report?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

[image]I have created report in SSRS that subscribed at particular time and sends PDF email.
I need exactly the same report, but with different parameter. Is any way to make SSRS automatically change the parameter value, and then send out the PDF report?

Where can I change my parameter here?

Comment: What version of SSRS do you have.  I have 2014 and the ability to change parameters is on that same screen.

Comment: Oh, mine is 2010. 
Does it mean I wont be able to do that?

Comment: Have you created a report parameter?  It is not shown on that screen indicating it's not part of the report.

Comment: No, my report doesn't have any parameters yet. I am just trying to understand if there is a possibility SSRS can do that in general. If yes, then I will create all parameters i need.

Comment: absolutely you can use parameters.  If the report has parameters, they'd be listed in the subscription settings under the schedule section.

Comment: Here's an example of a report with parameters.
http://imgur.com/wSVLSFu

Comment: Awesome. Thank you guys !!!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Data-Driven subscription for this.  One benefit of data-driven subscriptions is you can give a meaningful description the the subscription instead of it just being "Mail sent to ..."

When you set up the data-driven subscription, step 3 asks for a valid sql query.  For every row returned in the sql query, the report will be executed.  In your case, your query could be as simple as

```
select 'Value1' as ParamValue
union select 'Value2'
```

This will give you two rows, with a different parameter value in each row.

On step 4 you set up the options for recipients, subject line, etc.  Note that all of this can also be part of your query.

Step 5 is where you would set up your parameter value, and you'd choose "Get the value from the database" and in the drop-down, select your parameter name.

With it set up this way, the report will be executed twice (once for each row returned in the query from step 3).

One of the main things I use datadriven subscriptions for is when I must send the same report to multiple recipients, but the parameters are different for each recipient.  For example, we send a sales report to all of our sales reps.  The Sales Rep Code is a parameter for the report but I can customize the other settings for the subscription as well.  Using a table containing our sales rep data, I use something like this

```
SELECT
    SalesRepCode
,   SalesRepEmail
,   'Sales report for ' + SalesRepName + ' - ' + SalesRepCode + ', as of ' + GETDATE() AS SubjectLine
FROM SalesRepTable
```

This returns around 70 rows, one row for each sales rep.  For each row, the report will get generated using the SalesRepCode as a report parameter, the SalesRepEmail as the recipient, and the SubjectLine as the, well, subject line.  One subscription, 70 versions of the same report.